# Maximum number of audio channels over HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi

Is MacOS Mojave capable of sending more than 8 audio channels over HDMI?

For example, if I purchase a DisplayPort -> HDMI 2.0 adapter, will I be able to select more than 8 audio channels in the MIDI settings app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
It's not a Mojave limitation, per se - DisplayPort can only carry 8 channels, up to 192kHz 24-bit, max bitrate 36,864 kbit/s

Source [Wikipedia - DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I upgrade my MacBook and buy a USB-C to HDMI 2.0 adapter, will it allow 10 channels?